# Saving Google Form Response URL - Logic Issue

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

This script is designed to save the edit response URL to the response sheet - The trigger for this script is set to run on Form Submit. It works well for the most part.

The issue I have run into is once a user edits their response and hits submit, this script runs and overwrites the last row's Edit Response URL.

Just encountered this issue now and have not had much time to think of a solution. Want to throw this question on here as it seems like a rather interesting logical challenge.

Here is the script I am using:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
var editResponseURL = FormApp.getActiveForm().getResponse(e.response.getId()).getEditResponseUrl();
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SHEET_ID_HERE").getSheetByName("Form responses 1");
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn(), 1, 1).setValue(editResponseURL);
    }
```

My thoughts on solving this have been to somehow find a unique identifying value. Possibly something like the Timestap and Email address to generate a unique key to search through rows and if found set the value of the Edit Response URL. (And something like if values are null just write to the last row - When a new submission is done for instance.)

I will continue to update this post with new ideas. Interested in seeing what ideas the community has.

Update:
Added some new logic to the script - It fixes the issue above. Sadly it will still not work as Google App Script's on Form Submit Trigger is unreliable. (The trigger will fail to fire in some cases with no error warning.)*

Here is the updated script. (Hopefully this helps someone in the future.)

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {

var recordExists = false;

var editResponseURL = FormApp.getActiveForm().getResponse(e.response.getId()).getEditResponseUrl();

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SPREADSHEET_ID_HERE").getSheetByName("Form responses 1");
var responseURLs = sheet.getRange(2, sheet.getLastColumn(), sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();

for (var i = 0; i < responseURLs.length; i++){
if (responseURLs[i].indexOf(editResponseURL) !== -1){
recordExists = true
break;
}

}

if(recordExists === false){
sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn(), 1, 1).setValue(editResponseURL);
}
else {sheet.getRange(i +2, sheet.getLastColumn(), 1, 1).setValue(editResponseURL);
}
}
```

- Results from having my team preform multiple submissions:
  [image: Results from Submissions]

Comment: Is the edit Url different on each edit?

Comment: Nope maintains the same URL. Normal submission is done, url is saved. User then edits document, same URL is written. (Only this time at the end of the sheet instead of on the same row.)

Comment: If you have no uniquely identifiable method, The long method is to `e.response.getId()`  and compare it with all the other responses' id in the response store. If id already present, Do nothing, else setValue(). Alternatively, check the editUrlResponse column in spreadsheet for the same url before setValue()

Comment: Hmm that could work. Something like check if ID already exists, if yes find index and write to that row. If index not found write index and URL to last row. Will give it a try. Great suggestion. EDIT: Second thoughts I would probably need to check if URL already exists, not sure ID will remain the same. URL link does.

Comment: @TheMaster Hiya, updated my post. Feel free to add something as the answer and I will mark it as closed.

Comment: Since you wrote the code, feel free to add it as a good answer yourself(instead of a edit to your question). Also try `LockService`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the logical issue using the following code.

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {

var recordExists = false;

var editResponseURL = FormApp.getActiveForm().getResponse(e.response.getId()).getEditResponseUrl();

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SPREADSHEET_ID_HERE").getSheetByName("Form responses 1");
var responseURLs = sheet.getRange(2, sheet.getLastColumn(), sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();

for (var i = 0; i < responseURLs.length; i++){
if (responseURLs[i].indexOf(editResponseURL) !== -1){
recordExists = true
break;
}

}

if(recordExists === false){
sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn(), 1, 1).setValue(editResponseURL);
}
else {sheet.getRange(i +2, sheet.getLastColumn(), 1, 1).setValue(editResponseURL);
}
}
```

Please note this solution still has an issue. The delay between forms writing to the output sheet can cause issues when attempting to get the "Last Row".

Will update this answer when I come up with a better solution.